# Multiconnecting to Redux with react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

Imagine having in **react-native** app a lot of data that must be handled and shared across multiple components. As was investigated (by me) **react-navigation** will not unmount old layers so if any old layer was subscribed to **redux** it will remain subscribed so i will have a lot of subscriptions to **redux**. So will there be some performance issues or i`m wrong with something, maybe there are some ways to fix it.

Can someone provide any advises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe by layers you mean screens in `StackNavigator` - yes, these are not unmounted when you open another screen on top of a current one. It will unmount when you go back from it of course. Subscription to redux itself is not going to cause performance issues, you can easliy have hundreds of components subscribed at a time without any problems. What can cause performance issues is the way you handle redux subscriptions - e.g. reloading images, making requests as props change or expensive render. This is up to you to handle as a developer, and usually in a properly designed app underlying screens don't depend on state change caused by screens opened on top of them.

If you still want to play with it - take a look at [navigation.isFocused()](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#isfocused-query-the-focused-state-of-the-screen). You can make a [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) to wrap your screens in, and unmount the screen if it is out of navigation focus, but that will probably not be worth it